# Batch file to make another batch file to execute

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i am trying to make a batch file (lets say a.bat) which when run creates another batch file (lets say b.bat). Now, i am using b.bat to rename certain file.The code for renaming is,

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "folder=path\to the\file"

::Action
CD /d "%folder%"
FOR %%F IN ("old filename") DO (
 MOVE "%%F" "new filename"
)
```

The code in a.bat to write code in b.bat is,

```
@echo off

set VarOne=@echo off
set VarTwo=SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set VarThree=::Action
set VarFour=CD /d "path\to the\file"
set VarFive=FOR %%F IN ("old filename") DO (
set VarSix= MOVE "%%F" "new filename"
set VarSeven=)

echo %VarOne% >> %Output%\test.bat
echo %VarTwo% >> %Output%\test.bat
echo %VarThree% >> %Output%\test.bat
echo %VarFour% >> %Output%\test.bat
echo %VarFive% >> %Output%\test.bat
echo %VarSix% >> %Output%\test.bat
echo %VarSeven% >> %Output%\test.bat
```

Now the problem is that the when b.bat is generated it is like this,

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "folder=path\to the\file"

::Action
CD /d ""
FOR %F IN ("old filename") DO (
 MOVE "%F" "new filename"
)
```

The %folder% and a % from %%f is gone. So how would i get it right ? Help me please.

Comment: use 4 %s -> `set VarFive=FOR %%%%F IN ("old filename") DO (`

Comment: You must double each `%`

Comment: Thank you so much both of my bros.

Answer (score 0):

What npocmaka and LS_dev said in the comments was correct. You have to double each `%` and use:

```
set VarFive=FOR %%%%F IN ("old filename") DO (
```

I personally tested both of these and can confirm.